# What is the significance of demanding that a Jew write on the horn of an ox that they have no portion in the G-d of Israel?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, midrash

In reflecting over the concepts of Hanukkah there seem, at first glance, to be many contradictory and conflicting messages.

In the blessing related to Hanukkah we acknowledge, thank and praise G-d for the miracles, relief and salvation, etc. which G-d did for us when the Greeks attempted to cause us to forget G-d’s Torah and to transgress G-d’s will.

It then enumerates, contrasts and compares the *negative* attributes of the Greeks with the *positive* attributes of the Jewish people.

This is the general summary of the commemoration of Hanukkah.

But in contrast to this, we find only a few centuries later that the Greeks, Greek wisdom (consider Rambam’s Moreh Nevuchim) and language are accorded places of special honor by none other than Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel like is taught in Megilla 9b and Sotah 49b. That only a Sefer Torah written in Koine Greek is considered holy and valid from all the other languages of the nations. And of the 1000 students in the Yeshiva of Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel’s father, 500 studied the wisdom of the Torah and 500 studied Greek wisdom! It would seem that all the lessons from the Hellenists and Maccabees were forgotten.

And yet when summarizing the true message of Hanukkah, Torah says (see Bereshit Rabbah 2:5 and 44:20) that the Greeks demanded of the Jews that they write on the horn of an ox that they have no portion in the G-d of Israel!

How does this act represent and encompass the essence of the message of Hanukkah and how is this message to be understood in the apparently contradictory behavior of Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel only a few centuries later?

Comment: I once heard an incredible pshat to this. I'll ask the one who told it to me to repeat it and I'll post it tomorrow iy"h.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/on-the-horn-of-an-ox

Comment: @Menachem You might find the the Ma’amar of the Rebbe for this Shabbat, Shabbat Hanukkah from the year 5729 of interest…

Comment: The title of the question has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MichoelR That would be your understanding. But based on some other sources I have been learning it apparently is related.

Comment: The real question seems to reconciling Torah views of the Greeks. This issue is just one part of the negative side. It's a stand-alone question about this issue, or you can ask about the overall reconciliation.

Comment: @AYALTAAROG nu? :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @RabbiKaii coming right up.

Answer (score 1):

This vort is really part of a much bigger essay that I heard, but for this specific point here's the short and simple pshat that I was told. In Lashon Hakodesh the letter "Shin" in the beginning of a root generally denotes "Tameness", while the letter "Peh" in the beginning of a root generally denotes "Wildness". (Try this out for yourself.) In line with this a "Par" is a bull, while a "Shor" is an ox. The difference between an ox and a bull is, an ox is a castrated male while a bull is uncastrated. Symbolically speaking the ox is pictured with a yoke on its back while a bull is running free with a red cape flying in the wind (Hence the "Parah" Adumah's clearly untamed description.) Now, the horns of a bull are intended to be used for fighting. However, a Shor which is a castrated and tamed version of its former self, it has absolutely no need for its horns! Its horns are vestigial! Therefore, on a simple level since the horn of an ox is the perfect representation of the concept of "old-fashioned/No-longer-relevant", the Greeks forced the Jews to write that their religion is also no longer relevant on the horn of an ox.

Comment: @RabbiKaii here it is. And Yaacov Deane, I apologize that this pshat does not really answer your question regarding the more general understanding and consolidation of Hanukkah,  Greek vs Jewish history and Rabban Shimon Ben Gamliel etc. It is an answer though to the Title of your question. I hope you like it for what it is.

Comment: You may enjoy looking over Tikunnei Zohar  48a:9. https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.48a.9?vhe=Tikkunei_Zohar&lang=he

Comment: Also check this out

Answer (score 1):

B"H, I recently discussed this chiddush with my chavrusa.

In [Daniel 8:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.8.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it writes:

> and the goat had a conspicuous horn between its eyes

The Shelah HaKadosh writes [(Torah Shebikhtav, Vayeshev, Miketz, Vayigash, Torah Ohr 143)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Vayeshev%2C_Miketz%2C_Vayigash%2C_Torah_Ohr.143?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the exile under the Greek empire is named קרן (see also the [Daas Zkenim on Bereishis 15:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Daat_Zkenim_on_Genesis.15.12.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - horn. Why?

> The Greeks darkened the eyes of Israel and wanted to deprive it of any vestige of holiness, even of the reduced level of holiness Israel still possessed and symbolized by the ox's single horn

Furthermore, the Shelah writes:

> The Greeks demanded that the Jews inscribe on the horn of their oxen that they had dissociated themselves from the G–d of Israel.

But why on horns? The Shelah goes on to explain that in different places in Torah and Tanach, the word קרן is used in reference to:

- Moshe Rabbeinu; [Shemos 34:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Balak%2C_Torah_Ohr.6?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&p2=Exodus.34.29&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0)
- Torah itself; [Habakkuk 3:4 with Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Habakkuk.3.4?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)
- Priesthood; [Tehillim 112:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Balak%2C_Torah_Ohr.6?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&p2=Psalms.112.9&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)
- B'nei Yisrael; [Tehillim 148:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Balak%2C_Torah_Ohr.6?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&p2=Psalms.148.14&lang2=bi)

Regarding the horns of B'nei Yisrael, the Shelah writes:

> The Midrash continues that all of these "horns" were placed on the heads of the Jewish people, but they forfeited them due to their sins. [...] Provided Israel repents, G–d will restore these horns to their rightful place viz. Psalms 75,11: "And I will cut off all the horns of the wicked, but the horns of the righteous will be lifted up." This refers to the horns that the “Righteous One of the world,” i.e. G–d, had cut off. When is the time that He will restore them to their righful position? It is when G–d will raise the horn of His anointed: "He will raise the horn of His anointed" (Samuel I 2,10).

Comment: I appreciated yours and @Ayal Taarog's answers! Question on yours, does the Shelah's teaching here have a literal level of interpretation, that the righteous once had, and will be restored, literal horns? And if so what kind of horns, ox's horns, or some other type? It would be interesting if it tied into my question about Behemoth, if it was Behemoth's horns, but of course that would be far from the first conclusion I would jump to.

And then second question, are there any remazim or soydes what it means? Thank you.

Comment: @ShipBuilding Thank you. To be honest, I think this teaching is metaphorical.

Comment: Definitely but sometimes it is also literal and I wasnt sure if this was one of those times or not. 

What is its metaphorical meaning in these cases? Like, what makes Moshe Rabbeinu a horn? What makes Torah itself a horn? What makes Priesthood a horn? What makes B'nei Yisrael a horn? And are all four the same types of horns, or does each represent a different type of horn? Even among the ox family, Yaakov Deane educated me that there are 3 types, (Red Cow), bull (עגל זהב), ox and Aurochs. (פרה, פר, שור, ראם), and then there is the possibility of other types of non-ox-related horns.

Comment: @ShipBuilding I would strongly recommend reading the Shelah I mentioned. If you type ox on Sefaria, and then filter to "Shenei Luchot HaBrit", you should see every singel mention of "ox" of the Shelah. There are different places where he elaborates.

Comment: Thanks I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer but I remember one remez from the Hida about this is that Yosef ha Tzadik was like an ox, and the Shechinah rested upon him, so it was like the Greeks made klah Israel renounce the Shechinah, like saying the Shechinah is not with you anymore because just like the sin of the golden calf, where a calf was built and the Shechinah departed, you are sinning now also so the Shechinah is departed from you now also, and writing on the ox's horn demonstrates this. If anyone knows the exact source please comment with exact wording, please comment, since I am going from memory and I didn't read it directly but heard it in a shiur.

Also this may not be the Hida but I remember that Sukkot was instituted after the miracle that happened after the sin of the golden calf, and Honukkah was instituted after this happened, which has a parallel because both came after sins involving an ox or calf.

Sorry it's not a full answer. There is very little Torah I can recall and post that you wouldn't already know better than me, but hopefully there is something here good for someone reading. It felt like more than a comment although not a full answer either.

Comment: You too might enjoy the link to Tikunnei Zohar that I offered to AYAL TAAROG above . Thanks for your answer. It’s worth noting that the Hebrew, ראם is translated as Wild Ox or Aurochs. So you have reference to cow (Red Cow), bull (עגל זהב), ox and Aurochs. (פרה, פר, שור, ראם). Food for thought.

Comment: Also regarding your mentioned “forgetfulness”, you might enjoy this recently posted question. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132631/7303

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks very much Yaacov! I am always interested but have had trouble finding the full Tikunei Zohar in english in the past. This is the only full translation I have located and all 5 volumes have been out of stock everywhere for years. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Tikunei-Zohar-Rectifications-of-Splendor-Tome-5-of-5-Hardcover-9788894956986/865657002.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Regarding forgetfulness, tyvm  there too! I was concerned about that, so I listened to some Torah classes online about 1 yr ago, and there were many opinions but I thought the halachic ruling was better to learn everything & forget some than cover less but remember all. Shamefully even of that I remember almost nothing of it at this point. The only detail I remember was something about it's better to master specifics when u get to a certain topic but someone who doesnt cover everything cannot find the specific page about many topics to start with. Ofc I cant either so, uhh... lol.

Comment: @YaacovDeane As a late starter its overwhelming for me to spend yrs on just a few concepts but constantly hear people mention concepts that are foreign to me, and I dont even know it fits. I feel like I am lacking context even for what I am learning. For instance, if learning Torah is like charting a map, then I agree its not helpful to move on after charting half the USA to go try to fully chart Canada, but I feel like before spending 10 years fully charting the USA, I would at least like to learn the *outline* of the full world map, so I know where everything is in relation to each other.

Comment: @YaacovDeane But if it's not kosher then my opinion or feeling wouldn't change that or be that important. My big problem is I dont have a teacher right now, and I havent been able to find the right teacher and overall situation. The right teacher could know which sefers contain which teachings and they could help me layer new teachings, introducing new concepts the next day that also happen to go over and review the previous day's learning, but now with different sources introduced that also teach that teaching, so that I could progress at the same time as reviewing. But I dont have that so...

Comment: @YaacovDeane I havent been learning in the ideal way, and I know that. I am trying to fix that and look for a better situation. Thank you for your rebuke and advice. If you find out the halachic ruling about quantity vs mastering less quantity, please let me know, or maybe you are suggesting to by the Rebbe's ruling here regardless of Shulchan Aruch (or Mishneh Torah).

Comment: Please don’t take my previous comment to you with the link to learning & forgetfulness as “rebuke”. For details to understand, see chapter 32 from Tanya (1st section, Likkutei Amarim). I appreciate your sharing here very much & certainly have no negative opinion of you. My words to you are only from friendship, brotherhood & love.

Comment: Yes, I was specifically pointing you to the Alter Rebbe’s ruling in his Shulchan Aruch HaRav. I would suggest that you not rely on the “free translation & understanding” presented on Mi Yodeya for this. I have seen there is a recent, authoritative translation into English of the Shulchan Aruch HaRav available at Kehotonline. You should get yourself a copy and learn the Laws of Torah Study from there, in volume 5 (Yoreh Deah). It will help you in exactly the areas you are mentioning here. Be strong & do not be discouraged. Blessings only.

Comment: Thank you Yaacov! Blessings as well. Sorry if I misused the term rebuke. I will revisit chapter 32 on this. I have not read Shulchan Aruch at all though let alone the Rebbe's Shulchan Aruch HaRav. I will get it it for sure and start with that section. Thank you again for the positive encouragement.

Comment: After writing my last comment, I investigated the English translation of Shulchan Aruch HaRav at the kehotonline website. I am sorry to report that they have not translated the sections dealing with the laws of Torah study yet. It is only available in Hebrew currently. For what it’s worth, all this recent influence on this topic has influenced me to learn it again with my grandson in mind. There is never enough repetition…

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you for telling me. But they have translated part 1 where I could get started? In other words if I started to read Shulchan Aruch start to finish tomorrow, whats the difference between this version and Art Scroll and other english available editions? Is there a Daf Yomi equivalent audio version that I could listen to when I cant read it?

Comment: Yes, the translation of a good part (12 volumes) of Orach Chaim from Shulchan Aruch HaRav has been translated into English. Artscroll, to my knowledge is a translation of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch by Ganzfried. They are completely different texts. Here is the link: https://store.kehotonline.com/products.asp?dept=460

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks! What is this? https://mekorjudaica.com/shulchan-aruch-harav-hebrew-english-baal-hatanya.html

Comment: That is the Kehot Publishing edition.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Is it the Shulchan Aruch with the same commentary minus the Rebbe's commentary, whereas the Shulchan Aruch HaRav has the Rebbe's commentary also, or are there other differences between different translators? I will get the latter for the Rebbe's commentary anyway, but I am wondering if there are any other major differences besides using different translators for the Shulchan Aruch text itself. It doesnt say much in the description. The info may not be available, I might just call or email mekorjudaica, but thought Id ask here first.

Comment: Your question is really about the transmission and development of Jewish law and tradition. There are and have been many codes of Jewish law over the millennia. Over time, technology and society change so that Jews are  faced with practical questions about what to do and how to act in order to comply with G-d’s will. Shulchan Aruch was authored  by Yoseph Karo as an abridged version of his earlier work, Beit Yoseph, a commentary to an earlier code, the Tur. Centuries later, the Alter Rebbe wrote a new code based upon the Shulchan Aruch but addressing the issues of his day.

Comment: The Tur, composed by Yaacov ben Asher, was written in the 1300’s. The Beit Yoseph and Shulchan Aruch were composed in the late 1400’s to early 1500’s. Yoseph Karo was a contemporary of the Ari z”l, Yitzchok Luria. The Alter Rebbe composed the Shulchan Aruch HaRav in the 1700’s. The Aruch HaShulchan, an even later code, was composed in the late late 1800’s to early 1900’s by Yechiel Michel Epstein.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Which version is widely used to decide halachas? What I read online has consistently said that many Sefardim still use Mishneh Torah, but Shulchan Aruch is also widely used by Ashkenazim. In shiurim Rabbis I watch reference just "Shulchan Aruch" in relationship to halachic questions. I would want to buy whichever edition is the one I can read about a particular halachah and get the up to date authoritative judgement, but maybe even among Jews who go by the Shulchan Aruch, they still use different editions, or go by multiple? Which edition is generally the decisor?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I will get another teacher when I can, but for now I would just be reading on me own trying to learn what I can. It is worse than learning from a teacher but better than not learning at all and that is alternative right now. So if I read ten volumes which is very time consuming, I would want to read what is most authoritative. Then when I get a teacher, they can teach me specific halachas that go by another edition, or where multiple editions are compared, or where Mishneh Torah is the decisor even for Jews who normally go by the Shulchan Aruch,or whatever diff scenarios may exist

Comment: All the sources being mentioned are authoritative. What is appropriate for you personally depends on your background via your genealogy & life/educational/economic circumstances. The policy from MiYodeya is to advise you consult with your local Orthodox Rabbi. It’s clear from your comments that you need personal guidance. You should perhaps reach out to your nearest Chabad shaliach & discuss your goals. That will get you started.